# List names of files that are referenced by projects but don't exist on disk

Tags: c#

I have inherited some source code (Visual Studio solutions and C# projects) and have found a couple of scenarios where a project references a file that is missing.

Does anyone know of a tool that will recursively parse a directory structure, read each .csproj project file and list the names of any files that are referenced by the project file but that cannot be found on disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a code sample that does what you need:

```
string path = @"Your Path";

        string[] projects = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.csproj", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        List<string> badRefferences = new List<string>();
        foreach (string project in projects)
        {
            XmlDocument projectXml = new XmlDocument();
            projectXml.Load(project);
            XmlNodeList hintPathes = projectXml.GetElementsByTagName("HintPath");

            foreach (XmlNode hintPath in hintPathes)
            {
                FileInfo projectFI = new FileInfo(project);
                string reference = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(projectFI.DirectoryName, hintPath.InnerText));

                if (!File.Exists(reference))
                {
                    badRefferences.Add(reference);
                }
            }
        }
```

*This is just a scratch, but it will give you what you need

Comment: I was about to start down this path myself :-)